# Why does my Mac mini answers pings while asleep?

Tags: network, mac-mini, ping

My Mac mini late 2012 behaves strangely:

When awake the computer answers ping correctly:

```
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=4.201 ms 
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=4.823 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=5.108 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=4.400 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=4.523 ms
```

Right after going to sleep it stops responding, while it switches to 100 MbE:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
Request timeout for icmp_seq 11
Request timeout for icmp_seq 12
Request timeout for icmp_seq 13
```

But then, still sleeping, it responds again. It's still on 100 MbE.

```
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=14 ttl=32 time=3.897 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=15 ttl=32 time=3.918 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=16 ttl=32 time=3.906 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=17 ttl=32 time=4.090 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.12: icmp_seq=18 ttl=32 time=4.066 ms
```

This also works via IPv6. Why is this?

Comment: Is it possibly related to WoL?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't see any reason why.

Comment: The network card has to be awake to WoL so looks like it also responds to pings (or is this actual WoL)

Comment: Have you ruled out [bonjour sleep proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy) and that your router / switch might be responding to network requests while the hardware is asleep so that it can send a wake message to the hardware should you need to use a sharing service remotely?

Comment: Can be a sleep proxy or router as I detached all other devices for testing purpose. As soon as I disanle WoL, the Mac shuts down its ethernet port making itself unreachable.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/907903/wi-fi-still-connected-while-macbook-in-sleep-mode